# Install openCV in Centos

Tags: opencv, centos

I am trying to install openCV in Centos 6. When I run the command [root@cosmas opt]# sudo yum install libtiff4-dev libjpeg-dev libjasper-dev it returned the follow:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, presto
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * epel: mirror.fraunhofer.de
 * rpmforge: nl.mirror.eurid.eu
Setting up Install Process
No package libtiff4-dev available.
No package libjpeg-dev available.
No package libjasper-dev available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

What I am doing wrong? Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

**1. How to install and enable EPEL repo:**

CentOS 6

```
yum install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-6.noarch.rpm
```

CentOS 6

```
yum install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
```

**2. Install opencv dependencies:**

install base dependencies:

```
 yum -y install libjpeg libpng libtiff jasper-libs ilmbase OpenEXR-libs gtk2 gstreamer gstreamer-plugins-base
```

also you can search required libraries (*.so) or packages manually:

```
yum provides "*/*some.file"
```

**How to disable rpmforge repo**
edit */etc/yum.repos.d/rpmforge.repo*

set property

```
enabled=0
```

Answer (score 0):

As I can see you're trying to install debian-named packages via yum.

1. Disable rpmforge repo here /etc/yum.repos.d/rpmforge.repo
2. Try to run yum --enable-repo=epel search opencv
3. Install opencv

Comment: how can I disable rpmforge?